# Winning 8 points on answer without up or downvotes?

Tags: support, status-completed, votes, reputation

I just received 8 points for the following answer : [How to reset a QGIs toolbar](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/257173/25139).

[image: Reward]

[image: answer]

Apart the fact it was not my best answer on GIS SE (just answering with what was in comments) , i'm surprised I got 8 points even with no upvotes (until 2 minutes ago).

How can that be ?

I checked the rep page and nothing like 8 points amount is referenced:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment you have 3 upvotes and 1 downvote (net 2 upvotes).

[image]

I assume that when you checked, you received 8 rep because at that moment you had 1 upvote and 1 downvote. Sometimes it takes a while for the system to update :)

Comment: yes there can be a delay in votes/rep. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6174/how-is-reputation-calculated

Comment: Enlightning ! Strangely, I didn't realize 1 upvote + 1 downvote would equal 8, I guess I though basically 1 downvote was -10, so it would make 0. I should've read more carefully.

Comment: @gisnside Answer upvote = +10, Answer downvote = -2

Comment: @Joseph I have edited your answer to include a screenshot of the vote count

Comment: You can also visit the reputation tab on your user activity page to see all your positive and negative reputation in more detail.

Comment: @Midavalo - Thank you for the edit, that makes it much clearer :)